# storm v0.8.2 rebalance command not updating the number of executors for a bolt

Tags: apache-storm

I tried executing the following command:

storm [topologyName] -e [bolt-name]=[num_execs]

The command successfully runs but the number of executors remain unchanged. I tried to change the number of workers for a topology and it worked correctly.

Is this a bug?

Thanks
Punit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only increase the parallelism (number of executors) to the number of tasks. So if your component is having for example (number of executors: 50, number of tasks: 50) then you can not increase the parallelism, however you can decrease it.